# How to set up Clang/LLVM with Eclipse CDT Neon in Fedora 22?

Tags: c++, eclipse, llvm-clang

I am using clang 3.8 on my Fedora 22 machine.

I configured clang using the ninja build system, and it works really well using the command line. I can run the projects etc.

I was wondering if I can use Clang/LLVM with Eclipse Neon.1a.

I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32726175/unable-to-install-llvm-toolchain-for-eclipse-cdt) to set up Eclipse. But the problem is that when I compile my project, I receive the errors:

1. "Must #define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS before #including Support/DataTypes.h"
2. "Must #define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS before "         "#including Support/DataTypes.h"

Does anybody know if the linked post has some issue or is the ninja build system creating problem for eclipse as in the way it builds the binaries etc?

Thanks.