# Using Clang from Eclipse CDT under Fedora 28

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, clang, llvm-clang

I am using Fedora 28 with Eclipse Version: Oxygen.3a.
I have already installed the add-on for LLVM-Clang from "Install new software". I am using GCC/G++ 8.1.1.

I built Clang using ninja build system, and it works perfectly fine from command line. I am interested in LibTooling library, so, it serves my purpose. Then, I was trying to setup Eclipse with Clang (mainly for easy debugging), but it Eclipse always gives me linker errors.

I tried 2 solutions:

1. Followed this thread [Unable to install LLVM toolchain for Eclipse CDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32726175/unable-to-install-llvm-toolchain-for-eclipse-cdt). I made a hello world project, and I get the errors:

   clang++ -I/home/hassan/Tools/llvm-clang/llvm/include -O0 -emit-llvm -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -std=c++0x -o src/clang_test.bc ../src/clang_test.cpp 
   clang++ -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/32/ -L/home/hassan/Tools/llvm-clang/build/bin -o clang_test src/clang_test.bc -lstdc++

   /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/32//libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++

   /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/32//libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++

   /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/32//libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s

   /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/32//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc

   /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/32//libgcc_s.so when searching for -lgcc_s

   /usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/8/32//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
2. I set the include paths/lib paths to my already built (ninja build system) directory. It compiles fine without any problems, but I get linker errors, e.g., llvm::outs() could not be identified.

If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be great.
Thanks.